# Painting a triangle on a grid

Tags: java, for-loop, grid

This is how i need to fill in the grid:

[image]

For this method I need to fill in the grid like the picture above, the helperField meethod paints the while grid a certain color. I made the first for loop to create a black triangle in the top left corner, but to make another black triangle under it, the for loop I used does not draw anything. Could someone  please explain how I could finish the left side of the grid.

```
private static void drawHourGlassville(Grid_3x5 grid) {
    helperField(grid, Color.GREEN);

    // for left side triangle
    int counter = 0;
    for (int row=0; row < grid.getHt()-counter; row ++) {
        for (int col= 0; col <= row; col++) {
            grid.setColor(row, col, Color.BLACK);   
        }
        counter++;
    }
        for (int row=grid.getHt()/2+2; row < grid.getHt()-counter; row ++) {
            for (int col=grid.getWd()/3-1; col <= row; col--) {
                grid.setColor(row, col, Color.BLACK);       
        }
        counter++;
    }
}
```

Comment: You forgot to reset `counter` between the two outer loops.

Comment: Also, why does the number of black squares in a row for the lower-left triangle have anything to do with the *width* of the grid?

Answer (score 0):

Your logic is overly complicated.

Let's say height is 5. Think of two triangle like this, then overlap them and only use where they overlap:

```
*        *****    *
**       ****     **
***      ***      ***
****     **       **
*****    *        *
```

If first row is row 0, then number of squares in first triangle is `row + 1`, and number of squares in second triangle is `height - row`. For the overlap, the number of squares is the lower of the two, i.e.

```
Math.min(row + 1, height - row)
```

You can now do your logic for left side in a single loop.

To illustrate, this [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) code prints the coordinates to color black:

```
int height = 9;

for (int row = 0; row < height; row++) {
    int cols = Math.min(row + 1, height - row);
    for (int col = 0; col < cols; col++) {
        System.out.printf("(%d,%d) ", col, row);
    }
    System.out.println();
}
```

*Output*

```
(0,0) 
(0,1) (1,1) 
(0,2) (1,2) (2,2) 
(0,3) (1,3) (2,3) (3,3) 
(0,4) (1,4) (2,4) (3,4) (4,4) 
(0,5) (1,5) (2,5) (3,5) 
(0,6) (1,6) (2,6) 
(0,7) (1,7) 
(0,8)
```

Now, the right side is the same, except mirrored, and can be easily added to the code, to do both sides at the same time:

```
int height = 9, width = 15;

for (int row = 0; row < height; row++) {
    int cols = Math.min(row + 1, height - row);
    for (int col = 0; col < cols; col++) {
        System.out.printf("(%d,%d) ", col, row);
        System.out.printf("(%d,%d) ", width - col - 1, row);
    }
    System.out.println();
}
```

*Output*

```
(0,0) (14,0) 
(0,1) (14,1) (1,1) (13,1) 
(0,2) (14,2) (1,2) (13,2) (2,2) (12,2) 
(0,3) (14,3) (1,3) (13,3) (2,3) (12,3) (3,3) (11,3) 
(0,4) (14,4) (1,4) (13,4) (2,4) (12,4) (3,4) (11,4) (4,4) (10,4) 
(0,5) (14,5) (1,5) (13,5) (2,5) (12,5) (3,5) (11,5) 
(0,6) (14,6) (1,6) (13,6) (2,6) (12,6) 
(0,7) (14,7) (1,7) (13,7) 
(0,8) (14,8)
```

If the grid can be slim, i.e. `width < height`, then you need to add some checks:

```
int height = 9, width = 5;

for (int row = 0; row < height; row++) {
    int cols = Math.min(row + 1, height - row);
    for (int col = 0; col < cols; col++) {
        int col2 = width - col - 1;
        if (col <= col2)
            System.out.printf("(%d,%d) ", col, row);
        if (col2 > col)
            System.out.printf("(%d,%d) ", col2, row);
    }
    System.out.println();
}
```

*Output*

```
(0,0) (4,0) 
(0,1) (4,1) (1,1) (3,1) 
(0,2) (4,2) (1,2) (3,2) (2,2) 
(0,3) (4,3) (1,3) (3,3) (2,3) 
(0,4) (4,4) (1,4) (3,4) (2,4) 
(0,5) (4,5) (1,5) (3,5) (2,5) 
(0,6) (4,6) (1,6) (3,6) (2,6) 
(0,7) (4,7) (1,7) (3,7) 
(0,8) (4,8)
```